# Can't get a list of cast devices on the network

Tags: android, google-cast, chromecast

I'm trying to get a list of cast devices programmatically in Android, without using the MediaRouteActionProvider button in the SDK.

I create a MediaRouter and MediaRouteSelector like so:

```
mMediaRouter = MediaRouter.getInstance(this);
mMediaRouteSelector = new MediaRouteSelector.Builder()
   .addControlCategory(CastMediaControlIntent.CATEGORY_CAST)
   .build();
```

I then start discovery:

```
mMediaRouter.addCallback(mMediaRouteSelector, mMediaRouterCallback,
   MediaRouter.CALLBACK_FLAG_PERFORM_ACTIVE_SCAN);
```

In the onProviderAdded callback method, I only seem to get 3 providers: Android, com.google.android.youtube, and com.google.android.gms.  Only 'android' provides a route, which is named 'Phone'.

Why isn't my chromecast device showing up?  Other apps can see it, so I should have connectivity.

Comment: I'm on the same boat. YouTube can cast videos, but I can't do it from my own app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, what worked for me was this:

Add the onRouteAdded method on your Media Router Callback and look for devices with the description: "Chromecast"

Comment: This works.  It turns out that you only need to listen to the onRouteAdded callback, not onProviderAdded.

Comment: I am not always getting "Chromecast" description and it doesn't allow to connect but sometimes it works.

Answer (score 0):

You must listen for onRouteAdded and for onRouteRemoved for updates. Inside this methods you can ask MediaRouter for all available routes and filter only those with:

```
playbackType == MediaRouter.RouteInfo.PLAYBACK_TYPE_REMOTE
```